# This Connection is Untrusted in browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, https, ssl-certificate, payment-gateway

when i'm deploying the details to payment gateway in all browser ssl certificate error page is occurring .i don't know how to fix issue.please help. below is my attached error image for reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNto7.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several sites available explaining the issues with self signed certificates. The best approach here is to use either a free certificate authority like [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) or [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) or purchase a signed cert from a different CA.

More on the issue:

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-not-trusted-error.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate